# Unexpected behavior of references in a node graph

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0, c#-11.0

I'm trying to create an algorithm, which includes creating a node graph (and I am not addressing the fact that the algorithm is not yet complete and functional). I get an input from file and then create new node in graph or adjust already existing one by creating new Connection between nodes. My plan was that I could get from any node to any other another regardless of distance. When I edit "lamps" field, something gets wrong and one neighbor node sees that there are still some lamps, which is not true, because I just did "connection.lamps -= removeLamps". In debugging, I can see that this field is different in two references, but when I try to do ReferenceEquals (commented code), it just prints True everywhere. I thought that if I edit reference, it applies everywhere. Any idea why this happens?

```cs
internal class Graph
{
    public List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
}

internal class Node
{
    public int number;
    public List<Connection> connections = new();
}

internal class Connection
{
    public Node nextNode;
    public int lamps;
}

internal class Lamps
{
    private Graph _graph;

    public void GetInput(StreamReader sr)
    {
        Graph graph = new Graph();

        int places_count = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine()); // places

        for (int placeIndex = 0; placeIndex < places_count - 1; placeIndex++)
        {
            var spl = sr.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            int input_from = int.Parse(spl[0]),       // there is from A
                input_to = int.Parse(spl[1]),         // to B
                input_lamps = int.Parse(spl[2]);      // C lamps

            Node fromNode, toNode;

            if (graph.nodes.Any(x => x.number == input_from))
            {
                fromNode = FindInGraphByNumber(graph, input_from);
            }
            else
            {
                fromNode = new Node();
                fromNode.number = input_from;
                graph.nodes.Add(fromNode);
            }

            if (graph.nodes.Any(x => x.number == input_to))
            {
                toNode = FindInGraphByNumber(graph, input_to);
            }
            else
            {
                toNode = new Node();
                toNode.number = input_to;
                graph.nodes.Add(toNode);
            }

            fromNode.connections.Add(new Connection() { nextNode = toNode, lamps = input_lamps });
            toNode.connections.Add(new Connection() { nextNode = fromNode, lamps = input_lamps });
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(Node.ReferenceEquals(graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 3), graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 1).connections.First(x => x.lamps == 3).nextNode));
        //Console.WriteLine(Node.ReferenceEquals(graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 1), graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 0).connections.First(x => x.lamps == 1).nextNode));
        //Console.WriteLine(Node.ReferenceEquals(graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 0), graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 2).connections.First(x => x.lamps == 2).nextNode));
        //Console.WriteLine(Node.ReferenceEquals(graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 2), graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 5).connections.First(x => x.lamps == 1).nextNode));
        //Console.WriteLine(Node.ReferenceEquals(graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 2), graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 4).connections.First(x => x.lamps == 1).nextNode));
        //Console.WriteLine(Node.ReferenceEquals(graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 3), graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == 5).connections[0].nextNode.connections.First(x => x.lamps == 2).nextNode.connections.First(x => x.lamps == 1).nextNode.connections.First(x => x.lamps == 3).nextNode));

        _graph = graph;
    }

    private static Node FindInGraphByNumber(Graph graph, int number)
    {
        for (int graphNodeIndex = 0; graphNodeIndex < graph.nodes.Count; graphNodeIndex++)
        {
            if (graph.nodes[graphNodeIndex].number == number)
            {
                return graph.nodes[graphNodeIndex];
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof (number)} {number} does not exist in {nameof (graph)}.");
    }

    public int Proceed()
    {
        int counter = 0;

        while (_graph.nodes.Any(x => x.connections.Any(y => y.lamps > 0)))
        {
            for (int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < _graph.nodes.Count; nodeIndex++)
            {
                var node = _graph.nodes[nodeIndex];

                // if there is no path with lamps above 0
                if (!node.connections.Any(x => x.lamps > 0))
                    continue;

                if (IsEdge(node.number))
                {
                    if (node.connections.Count(x => x.lamps > 0) != 1)
                        throw new UnreachableException("IsEdge should handle this.");

                    var edgeNode = node.connections.First(x => x.lamps > 0);
                    int removeLamps = edgeNode.lamps;
                    counter += removeLamps;
                    edgeNode.lamps = 0;

                    for (int connectedNodeIndex = 0; connectedNodeIndex < edgeNode.nextNode.connections.Count; connectedNodeIndex++)
                    {
                        // path from neighboring node
                        var connection = edgeNode.nextNode.connections[connectedNodeIndex];

                        // if lamps are not zero or less
                        if (connection.lamps <= 0)
                            continue;

                        connection.lamps -= removeLamps;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        return counter;
    }

    private bool IsEdge(int number)
    {
        var connections = _graph.nodes.First(x => x.number == number).connections;
        return connections.Count(x => x.lamps > 0) == 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Serializing a graph is somewhat involved, since you will need to assign each object an Id, and replace any references with this id. And I'm not going to examine your code in detail to find the specific error.

But this conversion will be *much* easier if you represent your graph using a lookup table instead. Note that I'm going to use `Edge` instead of `Connection`, since I believe that is a more common term.

```
public class Graph
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<Edge>> Edges { get; set; }
}
public class Node{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class Edge{
    public int Next { get; set; }
}
```

Using this representation you all nodes already have IDs, so you can just serialize each dictionary key-value pair as a node Id followed by a list of edges. You can of course convert lookup representation to/from an object representation if you wish.

But my recommended solution would be to let someone else deal with this problem. Json.Net has support for reference handling and can do all of this for you:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Edge> Edges { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Edge
{
    public Node Next { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void SerializeGraph()
{
    var n1 = new Node() { Id = 1 };
    var n2 = new Node() { Id = 2 };
    var n3 = new Node() { Id = 3 };
    n1.Edges.Add(new Edge(){Next = n2, Id = 12});
    n2.Edges.Add(new Edge() { Next = n1, Id = 21 });
    n2.Edges.Add(new Edge() { Next = n3, Id = 23 });

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(n1, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
    });

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Node>(json);

    Assert.AreEqual(result, result.Edges[0].Next.Edges[0].Next);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, result.Edges[0].Next.Edges[1].Next.Id);
}
```

In general when it comes to serialization, doing it yourself should only be done for extremely simple things, or when there are no good alternatives.